# How to allow Azure App Service (ASP.NET Core Web API) to utilize app registration's API permissions?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi, azureportal

I have an app registration in Azure where I set the MS Graph API permissions. For local development I have developed a function to grab the app registration credentials from user secrets as shown:

```
    private GraphServiceClient GetGraphClientWithManagedIdentityOrDevClient()
    {
        if (_graphServiceClient != null)
            return _graphServiceClient;

        string[] scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        var chainedTokenCredential = GetChainedTokenCredentials();
        _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(chainedTokenCredential, scopes);

        return _graphServiceClient;
    }

    private ChainedTokenCredential GetChainedTokenCredentials()
    {
        if (_environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            var tenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_TENANT_ID");
            var clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_ID");
            var clientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET");

            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            // https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential
            var devClientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

            var chainedTokenCredential = new ChainedTokenCredential(devClientSecretCredential);

            return chainedTokenCredential;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ChainedTokenCredential(new ManagedIdentityCredential());
        }
    }
```

However I have deployed my ASP.NET Core Web API to an app service in Azure portal. When I run the API when deployed, it does not allow me to send an email similar to my local code so I am confident it is a permissions issue. My app service is set to managed identity. However I am not sure how to actually get my application in the app service to connect to the app registration in azure so the API can use the user and permissions to send the email.

UPDATE (1/24/2024) -

Based on the given response below I have put together the following powershell command but its unclear if these assignments of variables are correct:

```
$params = @{
    principalId = "6f5ndfasfasdfasfdf228"  <—— from app service managed identity tab
    resourceId = "a5cd32asdfdasdfsafasfd5db”. <——from enterprise page of app registration
    appRoleId = "6f5ndfasfasdfasfdf228" <—— from app service managed identity tab
}
$servicePrincipalId = “6f5ndfasfasdfasfdf228”  <—— from app service managed identity tab

New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $servicePrincipalId -BodyParameter $params
```

If i do run this I now get ew-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment_Create: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the app service to communicate with the app registration and utilize its ms graph api permissions through managed identities you need to enable the following api permissions in the app registration page first:

```
AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All and Application.Read.All, AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All and Directory.Read.All
```

Also in the app registration page click app roles and create a role and choose an allowed member type that includes application and be sure to enable that app role in the checkbox at the bottom.

Go to powershell and do the following individual commands

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All, Application.Read.All"

$params = @{
    principalId = “<App Service -> Managed Identity -> Object (principal) ID>”
    resourceId = “<Enterprise Applications -> Properties -> Object ID>”
    appRoleId = “<App Registration -> Manifest -> appRoles -> Id of that created App Role you did in first step>”
}

$servicePrincipalId = “<Use the same value as you did in principalId in the $params variable above>”

New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $servicePrincipalId -BodyParameter $params
```

This will now allow the app service to utilize the api permissions of the app registration using that app role you created and managed identities.

Answer (score 0):

Assign Application.ReadWrite.All application permission to the MSI.

However, there is no associated app registration in Azure portal.
We have togrant admin consent for the permission using Microsoft Graph appRoleAssignments endpoint.

Here is the official documentation: [Grant an appRoleAssignment to a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell)

```
$params = @{
    principalId = "9028***73e2d75e"
    resourceId = "8f***77bd5"
    appRoleId = "49***5c6"
}

New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $servicePrincipalId -BodyParameter $params
```

**Usage and Description**

[image]

```
PrincipalId: object id of the MSI.
ResourceId: object id of the Microsoft Graph service enterprise application.
AppRoleId: permission id of the Application.ReadWrite.Allpermission, should be a fixed value “1bfefb4e-e0b5-418b-a88f-73c46d2cc8e9”.
-ServicePrincipalId: can be the same as PrincipalIdor ResourceId. Both are OK.
```

Comment: In your example, ServicePrincipalId shows 028f but the principle id in the params object starts with 9028. Im slightly confused still whats what. The managed identity section of the app service is where i pull principalId, resourceId I pulled from enterprise as you listed, and appRoleId I used the principald value again above it. However its unclear what servicePrincipalId is? Sorry if these are dumb questions

Comment: Here is what i was thinking : $params = @{
    principalId = "6f5ndfasfasdfasfdf228"  <—— from app service managed identity tab
    resourceId = "a5cd32asdfdasdfsafasfd5db”. <——from enterprise page of app registration
    appRoleId = "6f5ndfasfasdfasfdf228" <—— from app service managed identity tab
}
$servicePrincipalId = “6f5ndfasfasdfasfdf228”  <—— from app service managed identity tab

New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $servicePrincipalId -BodyParameter $params

Comment: Hi @IrishRedneck [PrincipalId: object id of the MSI.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggnD4.png)

Comment: I get "New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment_Create: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." when i run this.

Comment: Just to confirm in case its stil a issue with my params . The ResourceId would be by to app services -> name of my web api-> identity tab-> Object (principal) ID?

Comment: Still unable to get this to work! Not sure why!

Comment: Hi @IrishRedneck, I have checked your update, according to the error message, we should try to login via this command `Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All, Application.Read.All"` to get enough permission.

Comment: That gets me to the next error: New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment_Create: Permission being assigned was not found on application . One step closer lol. On the app registration page the api permissions I set were Application.Read.All, Application.ReadWrite.All, AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All, Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, Mail.Send, User.Read, User.Read.All. Not sure what I am missing because i feel  I went overboard.

Comment: @IrishRedneck, you are using wrong `approleid`, the value should be `1bfefb4e-e0b5-418b-a88f-73c46d2cc8e9`. It's a  fixed value

Comment: I am using that one which you indicated in your answer. Still draws that error.

Comment: I finally got it to work!! I will post an answer.

Comment: Hi @IrishRedneck, since you have azure subscription, I would like to suggest you raise a support ticket to Azure Entra Team (AAD) Team. The answer I provided are general troubleshooting steps. Hope you can understand, after solving this, you can update this thread.

Comment: If you could check over my answer and let me know if I am forgetting anything but I used some of your steps as well as mine. I would say in your comments one thing did lead me down the wrong path. PrincipalId is actually the object id of the app service not the enterprise object id. Maybe a typo or I misunderstood your comment. However, thank you for all your help as your comments led me closer to figure out eventually. That approleid you sent me though,wheres that from? I had to use the approleid of a App role i created in the app registration and went to the manifest to get the id of it.

Comment: @IrishRedneck https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#applicationreadwriteall

Comment: Using that permission id as the approle works for you ? Strange it doesnt for me.